# How to fix the directory drive letter in eshell to run a NextJS project?

Tags: microsoft-windows, eshell, filenames

This bug is hard to describe, so I'll tell you how to recreate it.
I'm on Windows 10, emacs 27.2, & node v16.13.0. Here are the steps:

1. Open a default emacs (no init) with `emacs -Q` from powershell
2. Run `M-x eshell`
3. `cd` into a directory of your choice, run `npx create-next-app@latest --typescript` (doesn't have to be typescript to show the bug), and follow the prompts
4. `cd` into the project
5. `npm run dev`

After that I get the long list of module name errors. Haven't seen this on any issues pages or anything like that, so not sure what to do here. I have a suspicion it has to do with the `c` drive letter being lowercase and the actual directory being a capital `C`, but this could just be semantics.

Comment: Can you check whether `npx` or `npm` distinguish uppercase from lowercase drive letters, independently from Emacs? That might be one place to start. Emacs itself, and MS Windows itself, do not distinguish `c:` from `C:`.

Comment: It's gotta be `npm` because I made a next project from scratch rather than with `npx` and it still gave the same errors. It seems `npm` is fetching the current directory from the terminal it's using, and since `npm` checks I guess are case sensitive, the mismatching `c` drive letter causes all the craziness. If someone could point to a tool like https://github.com/sm-react/driveup for eshell, that would be awesome. I don't think I can edit the functionality of how npm checks, so actually changing the drive letter in eshell would be the only work around, no?

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you use the `driveup` tool in `M-x shell` instead, then reinstall all the dev dependencies, all the errors end up going away. That is a manageable solution since I could use eshell for everything else I'd use it for. Although the bug still is present, I wonder, how could you change the drive letter in eshell like the `driveup` tool does for powershell?

Comment: Maybe (also) consider filing a bug report with the maintainers of `npm`. I wonder if they really have a good reason for case-sensitive handling of Windows drive letters. I can't imagine any such use case/reason.

Comment: Just did to see what they say. Here's the link for other people that need to follow the issue https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4593

Comment: Good; hopefully they'll take care of it.